How to force Chrome to remove old versions of Chrome Extensions?
Chrome is eating my storage space day by day in gigabytes, so when I investigated the issue, I found that Chrome seemed like auto-update extensions and also not delete the old version which result to increase in disk usage. I am not sure how can billion dollar corporation like Google will be so dumb would not consider this.

As you can see in screenshot, 30 GB space taken by a single Chrome Extension, because it seems like this extension is getting daily updates.

So, any fix for this problem officially or utility to do cleanups?

Just searched for the same question and it appeared to be a decade-old problem. It's just insane.
https://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2014/01/chrome-doesnt-delete-old-extension.html
I think it's safe to remove all those old versions manually. Just done exactly that, no problem whatsoever.

ya multi billion organizations acting as dumb , its basic issue there should have fix in start but sad to see no fix till yet , i had to manually run scripts to check for big extensions , specially adblockers keep updating and each version increment +500mb on disk result massive disk usage
